# Natural deduction proof unsure if correct

Tags: solution-verification, natural-deduction

I'm unsure if this method of natural deduction is correct.

To prove: $P \vee F,\; \neg T \mathbin\rightarrow \neg P,\; T \mathbin\rightarrow B,\; \neg F \;\vDash\; B$

Proof:

1. $P \vee F$      (Data)
2. $\neg T \mathbin\rightarrow \neg P$  (Data)
3. $T \mathbin\rightarrow B$     (Data)
4. $\neg F$       (Data)
5. $\neg T \mathbin\rightarrow P$  (subcomp box)

   1. $\neg T$  (Assume **P**)
   2. $P$   (from 1,4,($\vee$E2))
6. $T$ from   (2,5,($\neg$E))
7. $B$ from   (3,6,($\mathbin\rightarrow$E))

[Reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOpdB.jpg)

I tried to solve using this method; I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Could you give a reference to the system you're using?

Comment: In substep 1 of step 5, I'm not sure what the bold $\mathbf P$ is supposed to mean; I would normally just write ‘assumption’ or something similar where you have ‘assume **P**’.  You shouldn't be referring to the proposition $P$ yet in this substep.  But the step is valid, by assumption, so maybe I'm being too pedantic.  Your proof is correct.

Comment: Having said that, I agree with @ShyPerson that it would be good to have a list of the natural-deduction rules that you're using.  I'm not used to a system with your rule $\vee$E2 as a basic rule (although I can see what you're doing with it, and it's a valid derived rule).  So if we have the list of rules, then we can verify that you're citing them all correctly.

Comment: (One other thing that I would do differently is that I'd write the box for step 5 *above* the statement of the conclusion $\neg T \mathbin\rightarrow P$, instead of below it.  But that's a matter of style, I guess.  If you're taking a class or working through a book, then you should probably do what they do for now.)

Comment: More or less correct... The starting point is $(\lor \text E)$ on 1st premise.

Comment: $(\vee\mathrm E2)$ appears to be "disjunctive syllogism":  $\phi\vee\psi$ and $\neg\psi$ entail $\phi$.